# How to force Mathematica to show a rational with the denominator I specified?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to write a function to force Mathematica to show a rational number in a denominator I specified. For example, the rational **2/3** with the specified denominator **6** should become **4/6**.

I tried using `HoldForm[]` or `Unevaluated[]`, but with no success.

```
In[1]:= setDenominator[x_, d_] := Unevaluated[Rational[x*d, d]];

In[2]:= setDenominator[2/3, 6]

        2
Out[2]= -
        3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a [FractionBox](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FractionBox.html) with [DisplayForm](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DisplayForm.html):

```
setDenominator[x_, d_] := DisplayForm[FractionBox[x*d, d]]
```

Comment: +1 Your suggestion works nicely for fractions, even when the denominator is not well chosen: e.g. `setDenominator[1/3, 5]`.

Comment: I made a variation of your solution that allows one to add and multiply the fractions.

Answer (score 4):

`HoldForm` works but you have to be sneaky to get the numerical value of `x*d` in there

```
setDenominator[x_, d_] := HoldForm@Rational[foo, d] /. foo -> x*d
```

This can be improved by adding some checks for the suitability of `d`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a variation on sakra's idea that allows for addition and multiplication...

```
Format[setDenominator[x_, d_]] := DisplayForm@FractionBox[x*d, d]
setDenominator /: Plus[left___, setDenominator[x1_, d1_], right___] := left + x1 + right;
setDenominator /: Times[left___, setDenominator[x1_, d1_], right___] :=left*x1*right;
```

Trying it out:

```
a = setDenominator[3/5, 10];
Print[a, " + ", 2/3, " = " , a + 2/3]
Print[a, " + ", 2/3, " = " , setDenominator[a + 2/3, 30]]
Print[a, " × ", 2/3, " = " , a * 2/3]
Print[a, " × ", 2/3, " = " , setDenominator[a * 2/3, 30]]
Print[a, " ÷ ", 2/3, " = " , a /( 2/3)]
```

[image: addition, multiplication, division]

Comment: @Qiang Li I added some code that lets you add and multiply unreduced fractions. setDenominator is based on sakra's routine. The upvalues trick is something I learned from Leonid. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200617/how-can-i-make-a-working-repeating-decimal-representation-of-a-rational-number]

Comment: @Qiang Li Thanks, I'm glad you liked it.

Comment: @Qiang Li I made the addition and multiplication capabilities a bit more evident in the latest version.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  That is puzzling, but I think you are right about the "x" multiplication symbol. I just copied the code from above into a blank Mma 8.0 notebook. It ran with no problem!  Anyway, I just added the \[Times] symbol to replace "x".  Let me know if that helps.

Comment: @Mr. Oops.  I didn't see that you had changed the "x" multiplication symbol.  (My browser hadn't refreshed when I did my last comment.) How did you change the "x" multiplication symbol? I inserted it via the Basic Math Assistant palette.

Comment: @Mr. But notice that added a new picture with the proper display of the "multiplication" sign. I can add it again if necessary.

Comment: David, I enter the characters with `|*|` and `|div|` (where the | mean Esc key), then I right-click, and Copy As > MathML.  That gives me some HTML entities (those ampersand...semicolon things), surrounded by MathML tags.  Pasting those entities into the edit box displayed the symbols below in the preview area.  I then copied those symbols, and pasted them back into the edit box, within the code area.  Rather complicated I admit, but it worked.  I am now going to delete my comments above.

Comment: @Mr. Thanks for the explanation. BTW, I still find it surprising that anything between quotation marks could cause problems. I used to think of the quotation marks as insulating the content from evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative for `sakra` example would be to store the value in string:

```
setDenominator[x_, d_] := ToString[x d] <> "/" <> ToString[d];
```