# How to show repeating decimal in different base in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I read [this great question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200617/how-can-i-make-a-working-repeating-decimal-representation-of-a-rational-number) about showing and doing simple arithmetic on them, but I am wondering given this (or simply starting from scratch), how to show and then further similarly do arithmetic on them when given a different base?

For example,

`(1/3)_2=0.01` means the fraction `1/3` in binary form is repeating the binary digits `01`.

Thank you.

Comment: By the way, it would be nice if we could enter repeating decimals directly through the keyboard through some keystroke combinations. That presumes of course that Mma would have an underlying knowledge of such decimals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an attempt. Mr.Wizard did much of the heavy lifting, especially in the base-preserving arithmetic.

```
rd[n_] := rd[n, 10]
rd[rd[n_, _], b_] := rd[n, b]

Format[rd[n_Integer | n_Real, base_]] := BaseForm[n, base]

Format[rd[q_Rational, base_]] :=
  Subscript[Row @ Flatten[{
     IntegerString[IntegerPart@q, base], ".",
     RealDigits[FractionalPart@q, base] /.
      {{nr___, r_List:{}}, pt_} :> {0~Table~{-pt}, nr, OverBar /@ r}
   }], base /. 10 -> ""]
```

Base-preserving arithmetic can be implemented using this:

```
Scan[
  (#[rd[q1_, b1_], rd[q2_, b2_] | tail___] ^:=
     rd[ #[q1, q2, tail], If[b1 === b2, b1, 10] ]) &,
  {Plus, Times, Power}
]
```

Checking to see that conversions to repeating decimals in several bases work.  Also checking routines for adding, multiplying, and dividing:

```
Grid[{{"n", "value", "decimal", "rd[n,10]", "rd[n,2]", "rd[n,3]",  "rd[n,7]"}, 
 {"a", a = 14/3, N[a], rd[a, 10], rd[a, 2], rd[a, 3],  rd[a, 7]}, 
 {"b", b = 2/5, N[b], rd[b, 10], rd[b, 2], rd[b, 3], rd[b, 7]}, 
 {"c", c = 1/2, N[c], rd[c, 10], rd[c, 2], rd[c, 3], rd[c, 7]}, 
 {"a + b", a + b, N[a + b], rd[a, 10] + rd[b, 10], 
    rd[a, 2] + rd[b, 2], rd[a, 3] + rd[b, 3], rd[a, 7] + rd[b, 7]}, 
 {"a + b + c", a + b + c, N[a + b + c], 
   rd[a, 10] + rd[b, 10] + rd[c, 10], rd[a, 2] + rd[b, 2] + rd[c, 2], 
   rd[a, 3] + rd[b, 3] + rd[c, 3], 
   rd[a, 7] + rd[b, 7] + rd[c, 7]}, 
 {"a \[Times] b ", a*b, N[a*b], 
    rd[a, 10]*rd[b, 10], rd[a, 2]*rd[b, 2], rd[a, 3]*rd[b, 3], 
    rd[a, 7]*rd[b, 7]}, {"a \[Times] b \[Times] c ", a*b*c, N[a*b*c], 
    rd[a, 10]*rd[b, 10]*rd[c, 10], rd[a, 2]*rd[b, 2]*rd[c, 2], 
    rd[a, 3]*rd[b, 3]*rd[c, 3], rd[a, 7]*rd[b, 7]*rd[c, 7]}, 
 {"a / b", 
    a/b, N[a/b], rd[a, 10]/rd[b, 10], rd[a, 2]/rd[b, 2], 
    rd[a, 3]/rd[b, 3], rd[a, 7]/rd[b, 7]}}, Dividers -> All]
```

[image: summary table]

---

**Edit**

The latest refinements (credit, once again, to Mr.Wizard) support nesting:

```
ClearAll[f, x, y]
f := (x/(x + 3 + 2 y) + y)/7 x; f
f // FullForm
x = 14/3; y = 1/3; f
BaseForm[N[f], 10]
x = rd[14/3, 10]; y = rd[1/3, 10]; f
x = rd[14/3, 2]; y = rd[1/3, 2]; f
x = rd[14/3, 5]; y = rd[1/3, 5]; f
```

[image: nesting]

Comment: I'll play around and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @Mr. Glad to have your help. You may be correct about the final line. When I dug up the old code, the final 3 lines were all hidden. Let me see what you came up with. At the present moment, calculation in bases other than 10 is not implemented.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ok. Good to hear that.

Comment: I removed the line `rd /: (h : Plus | Times) . . .` as that appeared to be redundant given the commutative property of `Plus` and `Times`.  Does the code as now shown pass your battery of tests?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your tweaks worked well for addition. I posted some results of tests in Edit 2.

Comment: David, what should happen when two numbers in different bases are combined?

Comment: @Mr. If the two numbers are in different bases I would default to base 10, but that's just a matter of preference.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  All the routines work fine. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I finally got it right, and you're welcome.  I'll remove some of the development comments above.  I am rather pleased with the visual symmetry of the current `Format[rd[ . . .` code.  I shall see if I can think of a more visually pleasing way to write the Scan/UpSet part.

Comment: David, I made an edit I'm not sure works.  If it does, it's a lot cleaner.  Please check it for me.

Comment: I believe that my latest edit allows for nested expressions such as:  `a = rd[14/3, 2]; b = rd[1/3, 2]; a + b + a/b + a*b + a + b + a^2 + b`  (Please pardon my schizophrenic editing.)

Comment: @mr. It works fine, as far as I can tell.  Really remarkable how much you were able to streamline the code.

Comment: Did you test the revision that includes `rd[rd[n_, _], b_] := rd[n, b]` and `. . . tail___ . . .` or the one prior?

Comment: @Mr. I tested on both (the version without and with `tail___`. The versions produce identical results for the test I used in Edit. You're difficult to keep up with!

Comment: Hello David, we have a proposal for a [separate Mathematica site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/37304/mathematica?referrer=hWeRiD9Qz0oIDM_9uBjtlA2) under the SE network, for anything related to mma (not just programming questions like on SO). We're very close to launching (24 users remaining) and it would be great if you could commit to that proposal :)

Comment: Ok.  Will be glad to contribute.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: `BaseForm[1./12, 3]` will show you 1/12 (the decimal point after the 1 is to ensure approximation) in base 3 as a repeating decimal.

Extra: Converting base x to base ten is even simpler `x^^<NUMBER>`

Comment: +1 for the decimal point, which I hadn't seen employed in `BaseForm` before. There is still something to do: your approach doesn't unambiguously identify the repeating part, but it is a great thing to know, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

'RealDigits' is able to handle all kinds of bases, so for instance

```
RealDigits[1/3, 2]

{{{1, 0}}, -1}
```

Refer to the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RealDigits.html) about the precise output format you may get. It can be rather complex.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. However, what I asked is how to do the exactly same thing as the original link did, showing the repeating decimal and then do some arithmetic such as addition/subtraction etc.

Comment: @Qiang The part of doing "some arithmetic" is a bit vague. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: For example, after showing the repeating decimal of `(1/3)_2`, I want it can deal with the situation `(1/3)_2+(5/3)_2=10_2`

Comment: @QiangLi Couldn't you just do the arithmetic as always and pipe the result through RealDigits?