# Is it safe to turn off Pattern::patv?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

By default *Mathematica* throws a warning message if I use the same name for both `Blank` and `BlankSequence` patterns:

```
f[{x_, ___} | x__] := g[x]
```

```
Pattern::patv: Name x used for both fixed and variable length patterns. >>

Pattern::patv: Name x used for both fixed and variable length patterns. >>
```

Yet the function works as I desire:

```
f[{1, 2, 3}]
f[1, 2, 3]
```

```
g[1]
```

```
g[1, 2, 3]
```

Therefore, is it safe to use `Off[Pattern::patv]` and continue as I please?

---

*I am aware of a variety of different, more verbose methods that can accomplish the same task, and it is not my desire to analyze their respective merits.  I am interested only in the safety of this specific one.*

Comment: Probably it is safe, but what is your use case? Is there no alternative? I kind of think it is not the best coding style if the possible length of x depends on the the type of input.

Comment: @Rolf There is an alternative:  `f[{x_, ___} | y__] := g[x, y]` but I think it is *less* clear.  Please explain why the original example is a bad coding style, show how you would write function `f`, and explain why that way is better.

Comment: @Simon see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8364321/618728) for an example where this could be used.  The `tail___` pattern can be replaced with `q2___` and `tail` in the RHS removed.  I did not make this simplification solely because of Pattern::patv, which I have learned to ignore, but which may concern others (or have a hidden problem I don't yet understand).

Comment: I just [did the timings](http://pastebin.com/38Fm1uGN) and although it *might* be safe to use `f[{x_, ___} | x__] := g[x]`, it's about 1.6 times faster to use `f[{x_, ___}] := g[x]; f[x__] := g[x]`...

Comment: @Simon that is the more common form, and it is a worthwhile point when wringing performance out of code.  However, in may applications it makes little difference.  Also, your preoccupation with micro-benchmarks is surely vexing WReach. ;->

Comment: @Simon, no offense meant by my edit above, but I would rather not have a bunch of sidebar answers each explaining how I can do this differently.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard: Actually, I find [that pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8364321/618728) really strange. What happens to the `q2` on the RHS when it doesn't exist/match on the LHS? I can see that it works, but I'm not comfortable with it. Similarly for the pattern in this question (and your first comment above), I think that the loss of clarity is not worth the saving in code. You could always use something like `f[{x_, ___}] := f[x]; f[x__] := g[x]` if the RHS of `f` is really long...

Comment: @Simon, halirutan and you are double-teaming me. :-) I know there are advantages and disadvantages.  I also like writing terse code, and I consider these more interesting uses of pattern matching part of the joy of coding for *Mathematica*.  Much like infix, I shall not attempt to foist this use on others.

Comment: Damn multiple overlapping comments here and in the answer below! And no offense taken by your edit. I understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @Simon you might as well add that suggestion to the existing answer below if halirutan does not.  It will keep them in the same place for any normal people seeking an alternative to my madness.

Comment: @Mr. What about `f[{Shortest[x__], ___} | x__] := g[x]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard This seems technically ok, but conceptually this is mixing variable binding and the pattern-matching. In other words, this relies on certain undocumented behavior of the pattern-matcher (which is not necessarily evil, just to note). What is worse is that this is rather obscure. If you are sure you will have no problem reading this yourself in a larger context a few months from now, *and* you only code for your own use, then I don't see a problem. B.t.w., another alternative: `f[{x_, ___}] := f[x]; f[x__] := g[x]`. Also, wrapping `Quiet` around `SetDelayed` is easier than `On/Off`.

Comment: @belisarius I shall admit, that is one alternative I had *not* considered.

Comment: @Leonid would you please consider giving that as an answer?  Also, you're only the third person to recommend that alternative. ;-)

Comment: This comment is not substantially different from the answer by @halirutan, to qualify as a separate answer, IMO. And sorry for the duplicate suggestion!

Comment: @Leonid, his answer is a suggested alternative, and example where misuse/misunderstanding of this method could case a problem.  Your comment is more of a conceptual answer to my actual question.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, if you so desire, have it your way...

Comment: @Leonid That sounds a bit like something a genie might say.  Do I get two more wishes?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I'm afraid this was the last one :)

Answer (score 6):

Your construction seems technically ok, but conceptually this is mixing variable binding and the pattern-matching. In other words, this relies on certain undocumented behavior of the pattern-matcher (which is not necessarily evil, just to note). What is worse is that this is rather obscure. If you are sure you will have no problem reading this yourself in a larger context a few months from now, and you only code for your own use, then I don't see a problem. B.t.w., another alternative (as already suggested by others): `f[{x_, ___}] := f[x]; f[x__] := g[x]`. Also, wrapping `Quiet` around `SetDelayed` is easier than `On/Off`.

*EDIT*

Here is my expanded view on the problem, added upon  @Mr.Wizard's request. A disclaimer is that these are just speculations, they may be totally or partially wrong.

The variable - binding stage is a mostly silent stage in evaluation of scoping constructs such as `Module`, `With`, `Block`, `Function`. The delayed rules formed with `RuleDelayed` also are scoping constructs, in the sense that pattern variables have certain protection from the name collisions with other scoping constructs, plus variable binding is happening there too. Variable binding is a process of associating a variable name with some value (obtained through expression destructuring for rules). For scoping constructs like `Module`, `With`, `Block`, `Function`, we have a good deal of control over the variable binding since we may override the Hold*-attributes of these constructs, writing something like `x=y;Function[Evaluate[x],y^2]`. For rules, the variable binding is happening inside the pattern-matcher, and is not as controllable. Normally, you don't think much about how the binding is happening, either because there is no ambiguity, or because the name conflict resolution semantics is spelled out in the docs or elsewhere (for example, there is a generic rule that for name conflicts in nested lexical scoping constructs, inner bindings are favored).

For the case at hand, you are at the mercy of the variable-binding mechanism of rules, and the way it interacts with the pattern-matcher. One fact (don't know documented or not) about the pattern - matcher is that it attempts matches left to right when given a pattern build with `Alternatives`. From  common sense, we should expect that the variable binding is happening after the match, and therefore your construct is fine. However, this is digging into internals over which we have no control. It may be, that there would be no other logically - consistent way for the pattern - matcher / binding mechanism to behave, or it may be otherwise.

As I said, this by itself is not necessarily bad - we often rely on some undocumented behavior if we have empirical evidence for a feature, *and* this feature allows us to do something non-trivial easily. My main objection of the construction is its obscurity - it is plain harder to read than the code using two separate rules (for me anyway).

Comment: Thanks Leonid.  Would you mind expanding this a bit, perhaps with some thoughts about variable binding?  I know you must have more to write; you always do. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, I added some thoughts on the matter, but not sure they are worth anything.

Comment: Thanks again.  I always appreciate your opinion and analysis.

Comment: Leonid I would like to rewrite [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8519194/618728) to eliminate this odd method.  Please show me how you would do it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I would use something like this: `PolarParametricPlot[rt : {Except[_List], Except[_List]}, rest__] :=   PolarParametricPlot[{rt}, rest]; PolarParametricPlot[rT : {{_, _} ..}, uv : {_, _, _} .., opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=  ParametricPlot[Evaluate[# {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} & @@@ rT], uv, opts]`. In this particular case, you method does save some typing and is elegant, but is still rather hard to digest :)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Actually, you can also reoder the definitions, so that `Except` isn't needed: `PolarParametricPlot[rT : {{_, _} ..}, uv : {_, _, _} .., opts : OptionsPattern[]] := ParametricPlot[Evaluate[# {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} & @@@ rT], uv, opts]; PolarParametricPlot[rt : {_, _}, rest__] :=   PolarParametricPlot[{rt}, rest];`

Comment: Okay.  This seems to introduce the problem that if `rest__` doesn't agree with the full argument test, the returned "unevaluted" function is not in fact what you wrote.  I find that troublesome.  One could include `uv : {_, _, _} .., opts : OptionsPattern[]` in the second definition, but with every pattern and Condition this becomes more clumsy, and theoretically, runs each test twice.  In the case where more than one argument uses Alternatives this devolves quickly.  How can avoid these problems while using the canonical method?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Well, good catch. You can change the second definition to this: `PolarParametricPlot[rt : {_, _}, rest__] :=  With[{res = PolarParametricPlot[{rt}, rest]}, res /; res =!= Unevaluated[ PolarParametricPlot[{rt}, rest]]];`, to solve this problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Probably not :) The issue of readability is very subjective, should be dealt with on a case by case basis. In this particular case, personally I might go your way. But as I said, this also depends on whether you want others to be able to easily understand your code or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I am going to start a new question on this topic, as I think it can be explored further.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No problem - that's interesting stuff (if only for people like us)

Answer (score 5):

When you switch the message off and afterwards on again, you write 3 lines to use your pattern. If you want to express that f should take the first element if it's given one list and take all elements if it's given more than one parameter, what's wrong with

```
f[{x_, ___}] := g[x];
f[x__] := g[x];
```

which is still one line less to write?

---

But to give an opinion about your pattern: The problem I see here is

```
f[{x_, __} | x__] := {x};
g[x__ | {x_, __}] := {x};
f[{1, 2, 3}]
g[{1, 2, 3}]

Out[6]= {1}

Out[7]= {{1, 2, 3}}
```

This would be kind of unexpected and maybe hard to debug. Using two definitions with different patterns does the job right:

```
f[{x_, __}] := {x};
f[x__] := {x};
g[x__] := {x};
g[{x_, __}] := {x}
f[{1, 2, 3}]
g[{1, 2, 3}]

Out[7]= {1}

Out[8]= {1}
```

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts.  I am talking about globally turning off the message by putting `Off[Pattern::patv]` in my `init.m`, so there are no added lines.  What you show is a very common form, but there are times when I prefer the form under discussion.  In your example the right-hand-side is very simple, but in actual use there can be significant code duplication.

Comment: halirutan: I didn't know you had posted an answer when I posted my comment above.  I put the comparative timings for the code in the question vs the code in your answer [here](http://pastebin.com/38Fm1uGN). (And welcome to StackOverflow!)

Comment: Simon: I saw it after I posted my answer.

Comment: Mr.Wizard: If your g[x] is a complex rhs, what about using something like 

f[{x_, ___}] := f[x];
f[x__] := g[x];

Comment: Your updated answer is much more interesting to me.  Thank you.  Three different people have recommended: `f[{x_, ___}] := f[x]; f[x__] := g[x];` so I believe that is the canonical way.  Regarding your update, it indeed is an added complexity.  However, it is an issue with `Alternatives` rather than `Pattern::patv`, though the former may be necessitated by the latter.  I agree with the implication that one should avoid ambiguity in code, but I would like to point out that `Alternatives` is no more ambiguous, and potentially less ambiguous than other structures in *Mathematica*. (continued)

Comment: The engine attempts to automatically order `DownValues` by specificity, but this leaves some ambiguity unless one maps and memorizes the specifics of that ordering.  Consider this (please do not complain about the poor design; it is merely a contrived example):  `f[h[___]] := "One" ; f[_[_, 1]] := "Two" ; f[h[_, _]] := "Three"` then `f[h[7, 1]]`.  I am at the mercy of the automatic ordering.  Suppose I wanted `"Two"` as a result? (continued)

Comment: Anyone familiar with *Mathematica* will know that the order of rules in a replacement is critical, and will be used to the idea of precedence.  Using `Alternatives` it is a simple matter to manually order the rules as I choose.  I can write:  `g[_[x_, 1] | h[_, x_] | h[x___]] := {x}` then `g[h[7, 1]]` and get `{7}` showing that the first matching rule was used.  Therefore using `Alternatives` can in fact be less arbitrary that automatic ordering.