# How to draw line 'y=x' using PolarPlot in mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

Because `PolarPlot` should type r=... type of command.

But y=x will cause r to disappear.

How to draw that line with `PolarPlot`?

Comment: Could you explain a bit of what you're trying to accomplish? There may be a better way of doing what you want.

Comment: Sorry for the unclear question. I want a general form that I can draw the picture that r is elimiated. Example 1: rcosx=rsin(2x). Example 2: rsin(3x)=rcos(x)*sin(2x). All the example's r is disappeared. Now thank for many people give answers to me, but I haven't understand which is the better way for my question clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use a new function for things like this.

```
PolarParametricPlot[
  {rT : {_, _} ..} | rT : {_, _},
  uv : {_, _, _} ..,
  opts : OptionsPattern[]
] := 
  ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[# {Cos@#2, Sin@#2} & @@@ {rT}],
    uv, 
    opts
  ]
```

Usage:

```
PolarParametricPlot[{t, 45 Degree}, {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @Harm You could also just turn off that message completely as there is [apparently no good reason for it.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374056/is-it-safe-to-turn-off-patternpatv)  Similarly I believe most people turned off `General::spell1` after a while.

Comment: @Harm thanks for the vote, but I didn't mean to twist your arm, and I agree with you about concise solutions.  I wrote/adapted `PolarParametricPlot` before `PolarPlot` was introduced, and I still find it useful.  I don't know of a more concise approach for this family of plots.

Comment: @Harm, PolarPlot was [added in version 6.](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/NewIn60FunctionVisualization.html)

Answer (score 3):

First, consider `Plot[]` which "generates a plot of f as a function of x from xmin to xmax" (I'm quoting the *Mathematica* documentation).  You can't use it to plot a vertical line satisfying the equation x = x0, because the latter is not a function of x: instead of being single-valued, it has infinitely many values at x0.

Similarly, `PolarPlot[]` cannot be used to draw a straight line that passes through the origin, because its equation is not a function of θ: it has infinitely many values at a particular θ (equal to Pi/4 in the case requested), but none at all elsewhere.  (Well, one could also allow the complementary angle 3Pi/4 as well.)

So I maintain it can't be done using the tools specified, short of the cheat

```
PolarPlot[0, {\[Theta], 0, 1}, 
   Epilog -> Line[{Scaled[{1, 1}], Scaled[{0, 0}]}]]
```

Comment: You can plot vertical lines using `ParamtericPlot`. Technically `PolarPlot` and `Plot` are just special cases of `ParametricPlot`

Comment: How to use ParamtericPlot to plot r=1 & x=y ? What the example I found is too difficult to understand...

Answer (score 2):

Here is the general polar form for a line of the form *y = m x + b*:

```
In[155]:= r /. 
 Solve[Eliminate[{x == r Cos[t], y == r Sin[t], y == m x + b}, {x, 
    y}], r]

Out[155]= {-(b/(m Cos[t] - Sin[t]))}
```

The solution vanishes when the y-intercept *b* is zero.  This makes sense, since such lines are drawn at a constant angle, which is problematic since `PolarPlot` works by varying the angle.

You could approximate such a line by using a very small value for *b*, but there are probably better approaches.

Comment: Trying to plot the solution `y == x` with this is also problematic because it deviates ever so slightly no matter what b you choose.

Comment: This solution seems great as general form,but how to draw picture by this method? Thank you~

Answer (score 1):

You could draw the line using `ListPolatPlot`:

```
ListPolarPlot[{{Pi/4, 5}, {5 Pi/4, 5}}, Joined -> True]
```