# Handling flexible arguments in Mathematica functions

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, arguments, user-defined-functions

This is an offshoot and extension of: [Is it safe to turn off Pattern::patv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8374056/is-it-safe-to-turn-off-patternpatv/8378171#comment10549714_8378171)

Many built-in *Mathematica* functions allow flexible arguments.  In user-defined functions I have been using `Alternatives` for this purpose, but comments and answers to the question referenced indicate that this is at least nonstandard, and perhaps undesirable.

Let me define a dummy function `foo` as an example.

```
Off[Pattern::patv]

p = {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ};

foo[
  {x : p ..} | x : p,
  {y__} | y__,
  ops : OptionsPattern[]
] /; Max[y] <= 10  :=  bar[#, y, ops] & /@ {x}
```

`foo` accepts, in order:

- an object matching patten `p`, or a list of such objects.
- a set of implicitly numeric objects with a maximum value of 10, either as a list or a sequence of arguments (as written these objects themselves could be numeric lists with a maximum value of 10)
- options matching `OptionsPattern[]`

If any of these conditions are not met, `foo[args]` is returned unevaluated.

The two pattern using `Alternatives` (`|`) are the most common cases, but they are not exclusive.

I struggle to see how `foo` should best be implemented.

- What is the canonical way to accomplish this?
- What are its advantages over using `Alternatives`?
- Is it objectively easier to read?

Answer (score 4):

I believe that there are three canonical ways of dealing with flexible arguments:

1. anything goes: `f[x_]`,
2. multiple forms: `f[{x : p ..}]` and `f[x:p]`, where one calls the other, and
3. alternation: `f[{x : p ..} | x : p]`.

The primary difference is where you deal with the added complexity of flexible arguments. Each can have its advantages.

The primary advantage of anything goes is simplicity in creating the acceptable patterns, but this leaves the processing to the internals of the function which increases its complexity. See the [ErrorBarPlots](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ErrorBarPlots/guide/ErrorBarPlottingPackage.html) `.m` file for a good example of this. Ultimately, though, `ErrorListPlot` relies on the second method hidden behind the facade of the first method.

The multiple forms method pushes the complexity onto the dispatcher in choosing the correct alternative.  It has the simplest functional form as one form usually calls another form with the "correct" layout of the data.  The difficulty with this method is the exponential growth of function specifications with the number of parameters with alternatives. This can be limited by adopting a hybrid approach, like that found in `ErrorListPlot`.

Alternation has the most complex pattern form, and may require special processing to extract the alternatives similar to anything goes.  Also, the patterns themselves can be more difficult to construct, and because of the potential for extra processing, this method should be used least often of the three. However, in some cases, like in your code, this method can be the most straightforward implementation.

Comment: Thanks for answering.  Please include some code samples, specifically how you would implement "If any of these conditions are not met, foo[args] is returned unevaluated." with methods 1. and 2.  (I know Leonid's method, but is it what you use?)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, give me a couple of hours. I wrote this off the top of my head, and hadn't fleshed out any code samples.